# How do change streams work in mongo across multiple instances?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, redis, changestream

Let's assume I have two data centers each with 3 instances running the same code connected to a single MongoDB and separate Redis databases.

```
Redis A <----> Data Center A
                            |
                            |--------> MongoDB
                            |
Redis B <-----> Data Center B
```

The expectation is that when a certain collection in Mongo is updated, a change stream in both Data Center A and B will be triggered to clear the redis cache. Will it work with change streams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have a changestream code running on n nodes/instances each instance will receive the change event and based on that event & data from changestream you can do your businesslogic/redis cleanup.

1. Let say you have changestream listener(CS1) running on Data Center A and this data center has redis server A which you want to clean up on certain condition from DB change event.
2. Let say you have another changestream listener(CS2) running on Data Center B and this data center has redis server B which you want to clean up on certain condition from DB change event.
3. Both changestream listeners(CS1 & CS2) listening to same DB and same collection.
4. When any change happens on the collection the change event will be received by both changestream listeners(CS1 & CS2)
5. CS1 will have logic to cleanup redis A & CS2 will have logic to cleanup redis B so when change event comes and condition met your both redis server will be cleaned.

Comment: Is it possible that they stop working at some point. I tested one day and they were both cleared. Tested the next day and just one was cleared. Had to restart one of the datacenters to make things work again.

Comment: Did you seen any error in changestreamlister app logs? Also changestream provides resume token functionality. So you may have your changestream application logs monitored and when error happens you can simply restart application with resume token. When you get change event you need to store that resume token in some storage like redis or DB etc and on restart of changestream you listen to changestream with resume tooken.